# Angular Test for Bootstrap $modal controller componant

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Below is the code for part of a controller I am trying to unit test but I'm not having much luck. I keep getting the error message Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for account().

Controller

```
    $scope.confirmDelete = function (account) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/app/accounts/views/_delete.html',
            controller: function (global, $scope, $modalInstance, account) {
                $scope.account = account;

                $scope.delete = function (account) {
                    global.setFormSubmitInProgress(true);
                    accountService.deleteAccount(global.activeOrganizationId, account.entityId).then(function () {
                        global.setFormSubmitInProgress(false);
                        $modalInstance.close();
                    },
                    function (errorData) {
                        global.setFormSubmitInProgress(false);
                    });

                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    global.setFormSubmitInProgress(false);
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            },
            resolve: {
                account: function () {
                    return account;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (asset) {
            $scope.getAll(1, 100);
        }, function () {
            console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
```

the test

```
describe("confirmDelete() function", function () {
        var controller, scope;

        // sets scope of controller before each test
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$modal_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('AccountsController',
                {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $stateParams: mockStateParams,
                    $state: mockState,
                    // below: in order to call the $modal have it be defined and send on the mock modal? 
                    $modal: _$modal_, 
                    //modalInstance: mockModalInstance,
                    global: mockGlobal,
                    accountService: mockAccountSrv
                });
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($modal) {
            spyOn($modal, 'open');
            spyOn(scope.modalInstance, "account");
        }));

        it("make sure modal promise resolves", function () {
            scope.confirmDelete(mockAccountSrv.account);
            expect($modal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the second `beforeEach` you are trying to spy on `scope.modalInstance` and such field does not exist. Thus, Jasmine cannot find object to spy upon.

Another problem is that you use the `result` promise of the modal so you have tell your mock to return it in order not to get TypeError.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($modal, $q) {
    spyOn($modal, 'open').and.returnValue({
        result: $q.defer().promise
    });
)
```

Next step will be to return a promise that you can resolve in unit test so you can verify correct behavior when it is resolved or rejected. You can simulate modal window closing that way.

Read more about spies in the [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies).

Also note that you don't have to inject modal service into controller (I mean the `$modal: _$modal_` line). Services are singletons. When you spy on any instance of it, it will spy it everywhere.

Comment: that makes sense except now I get a TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'modalInstance.result'). I was thinking I have to make a fake mock modal but I cant seem to get that to work quite yet. I also had the below code to get rid of the error, am I on the right track?      mockModalInstance.result = function (promiseHandler) {
          return promiseHandler();
      };